# How to get internal doc id set by lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I've indexed some documents in the index module. Intuitively, Lucene set `IDs` for any indexed document. These `IDs` may not have a specific order though. Concretely, the first doc ID is set to `127`, the second one is set to `133` and so on...

In the search module, I have the document (which I want to process), But I'm trying to get these already-set `docIDs` (that was set by Lucene in index time) See the code below:

```
private long calculateProbabilityOfDocument(String topic, Document doc){   

  Terms termVector = iReader.getTermVector(DOCID, FIELD);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think Lucene may not let me access the internal IDs. Is there any other approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally could end up finding the solution.

I found out that lucene does not allow access to its internal document IDs. However, we can **iterate through the documents** and get their `TermVector`. Seems that it's the only possible way to get term vectors. I'm using the script below:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("Body", new EnglishAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.parse(topic);
TopDocs hits = iSearcher.search(query, 1000);
for (int i=0; i<hits.scoreDocs.length; i++){
     Terms termVector = iSearcher.getIndexReader().getTermVector(hits.scoreDocs[i].doc, "Body");
     Document doc = iSearcher.doc(hits.scoreDocs[i].doc);
     documentsList.put(doc, termVector);
}
```